# How can I extract the linux version and gcc version of the proc file?

Tags: linux, gcc, scripting

As the question says, im wondering how to get the linux and gcc versions from the proc file. I know that I have to use `cat /proc/version` but the result is too much of (to me) unnecessary information. If I run the command I get this: `MINGW64_NT-10.0-19042 version 3.1.6-340.x86_64 (@fv-az314) (gcc version 9.3.0 (GCC) ) 2020-07-09 14:33 UTC`(the command was run in cmder bash.exe). What I want instead is to only get `3.1.6-340.x86_64`(linux version) and `9.3.0`(gcc version). I understand there are certain commands that allow for this sort of info extraction but as i am new to bash scripting I don't know how to go about doing that. My wanted output is: `Linux: <linux version> \n gcc: <gcc version>` (where \n is the new line character).

Any and all help is apreciated.

Comment: If you use `gcc`, you are coding in C. Then use [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), in particular [uname(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kept your "formatting", though I'm not sure that's what you actually want.

```
awk '{printf "Linux: %s \n gcc: %s", $3, gensub(/^.*gcc version ([^ ]+).*$/, "\\1","1",$0)}' /proc/version
Linux: 5.4.0-72-generic 
 gcc: 9.3.0tink@linux:~
```

Comment: This is exactly what i'm looking for.

Comment: @simsam - you're welcome. Caveat:  I've tried this on 4 different Linux installations two different versions of Ubuntu, RHEL and an older Centos, and they all worked fine. There's a chance that there are distro's out there where the kernel version is **not** the 3rd field.

Answer (score 1):

The code would be :

```sh
var1=$(uname -r)
var2=$(gcc -dumpversion)
echo -e "Linux version is $var1 \n gcc version is $var2"
```

This should give you your required output

Comment: The kernel might have been compiled with a [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler different of the one available, and in some cases, GCC is not even installed

Comment: This works too but I'm not allowed to use the `uname` command.